# Interpreting parameter values from scipy stat and popt

Tags: python, math, floating-point

Really dumb question, but I am new to python and my math is super rusty. 
I ran a function using the curve_fit function in python and got a list of parameter my parameter for my A and B variable came out as 3.93123642e+01  1.98760388e-02

Is the true number value for A now equal to 3.931236420
and B is 0.0198760388?

Is e similar to 10^x in this case?

Comment: `e+01` means `*10`, so your first number is 39.31236420

Comment: But yes, in general `e+XX` means `*10^(XX)`